# Cannot resolve symbol (string)

Tags: java, android

Simple question, why is this happening?

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.maxiesnax.gavinisms2.gavinisms2.R;



public class GavinFragment extends Fragment {
;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gavin, container, 
false);



    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;

    final MediaPlayer aahMP = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.aaah);

    Button play_aaah = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.play_ahhh);

    play_aaah.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            aahMP.start();
        }
    });

}


}
```

this is my code for my Fragment containing the button for aah.mp3 to be played. The error occurs at

```
(R.id.play_ahhh);
```

specifically the play_ahhh when it's already defined in the XML.

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Gavinisms</string>

<string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>

<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

<string name="play_ahhh">Ahhh"</string>
<!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
<string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: `play_ahhh`, as you have it defined, would be in `R.string`, not `R.id`. That's why you're getting the "Cannot resolve symbol" error. But you don't find `View`s by the text you've set on them. You find them by their IDs; i.e., the value of the `android:id` attribute you've set in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
<string name="play_ahhh">Ahhh"</string>
```

to

```
<string name="play_ahhh">Ahhh</string>
```

Also you should use the rootView in fragments

```
Button play_aaah = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.play_ahhh);
return rootView;
```

Answer (score 0):

In below line remove double quotes inside text,

```
<string name="play_ahhh">Ahhh"</string
```

Change to ,

```
<string name="play_ahhh">Ahhh</string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<string name="play_ahhh">Ahhh</string>
```

I also find one possible bug in your code...

```
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
return rootView;
```

Move this line to the bottom of onCreateView() function. It won't execute codes after return statement. I will also suggest you read some java related books, something like "Think in Java."